How to change the color of the TextField cursor handle in Compose Material 3?
Specifically, the CompositionLocalProvider approach works for a BasicTextField but not for a TextField:
    val customTextSelectionColors = TextSelectionColors(
        handleColor = Red,
        backgroundColor = Red.copy(alpha = 0.4f)
    )

    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextSelectionColors provides customTextSelectionColors) {
        // No effect here:
        TextField(
            value = textValue,
            onValueChange = {
                textValue = it
            }
        )
        // Works here: cursor handle is red:
        BasicTextField(value = textValue, onValueChange = {
            textValue = it
        })
    }

How can I change the cursor handle color of a TextField?

Works for me, I cannot reproduce the problem. The question is similar to: How to change TextField's highlighted text color on Jetpack Compose?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Use colors parameter in the TextField
TextField(
    value = textValue,
    onValueChange = { textValue = it },
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
        selectionColors = TextSelectionColors(
             handleColor = Color.Red,
             backgroundColor = Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.4f)
        )
    )
)

